# Is there a way to prevent SQL Server from automatically formatting my view query?

Tags: sql-server

It's ok to have a common format, I have mine, me and my team uses the same format when writing SQL.

Now here is the problem: we use SQL Server. I wrote a long view, then, to remember what I did, I opened the "design" of that view. And I noticed that SQL Server completely screwed my format, and applied its own. Even worse, it duplicate simple conditions and make them longer for no reason (maybe I'm judging a bit to fast... but...)

Here is my example, sorry it's a very long condition, you don't have to read it, just notice the format:

```
WHERE                        (STATUT_CAND IN (2, 3)) 
    AND 
                         (DATE_DISPO < GETDATE() OR DATE_DISPO IS NULL) 
    AND
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(ID_CAND) AS Expr1
                             FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_RESULT_ENTREVUE AS pcre
                             WHERE        (ID_CAND = PC.ID_CAND)) > 0)
    AND
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(MATR) AS Expr1
                             FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_EMPL AS PAI_DOS_EMPL_1
                             WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (ETAT = 'C14' OR
                                                      ETAT = 'C15' OR
                                                      ETAT = 'E1') OR
                                                      (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (ETAT LIKE 'A%' OR
                                                      ETAT LIKE 'P%' OR
                                                      ETAT LIKE 'S%') AND (STAT_ENG = 'E1' OR
                                                      STAT_ENG = 'P1' OR
                                                      STAT_ENG = 'G1')) <= 0) 
    AND 
                         (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        ID_CAND
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_EMPL AS PAI_CAND_EMPL_1
                           WHERE        (ID_CAND = PC.ID_CAND) AND (MOTIF_EXCLUS IS NOT NULL) AND (MOTIF_EXCLUS NOT IN ('0')))) 
    AND                  (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        MOT_ABS
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_PMNT_ABS AS PAI_DOS_PMNT_ABS_1
                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (MOT_ABS = '15' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '16' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '40' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '41' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '45' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '46' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS >= '52' AND MOT_ABS <= '57') OR
                                                     (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (MOT_ABS = '01') AND (CODE_PMNT >= 103522 AND CODE_PMNT <= 103541 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103572 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103573 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103577)))
    AND                  (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        STAT_ENG
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_EMPL AS pados
                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (DATE_EFF > GETDATE()))) 
    AND                  (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        MOTIF_AFF
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.GRH_POSTE_AFFECT AS pados
                           WHERE        (PC.MATR = MATR) AND (MOTIF_AFF LIKE '%S%') AND (DATE_EFF =
                                                         (SELECT        MAX(DATE_EFF) AS Expr1
                                                           FROM            Paie.dbo.GRH_POSTE_AFFECT AS aff
                                                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR))))) 


    AND                 ( EXISTS 
                        (SELECT        MATR
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_HCHQ_PMNT AS dosem
                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (DATE_FIN > DATEADD (year , -3 , GETDATE() ))) or (select DATE_DERN_PAIE from paie.dbo.PAI_DOS where MATR = PC.MATR) >  DATEADD (year , -3 , GETDATE() ) or (select DATE_DERN_PAIE from paie.dbo.PAI_DOS where MATR = PC.MATR) is null)
```

This way, I know where the MAIN `AND` are, now when I put this into the view, this is how SQL Server format it :

```
WHERE        (STATUT_CAND IN (2, 3)) AND (DATE_DISPO < GETDATE() OR
                     DATE_DISPO IS NULL) AND
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(ID_CAND) AS Expr1
                             FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_RESULT_ENTREVUE AS pcre
                             WHERE        (ID_CAND = PC.ID_CAND)) > 0) AND
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(MATR) AS Expr1
                             FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_EMPL AS PAI_DOS_EMPL_1
                             WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (ETAT = 'C14' OR
                                                      ETAT = 'C15' OR
                                                      ETAT = 'E1') OR
                                                      (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (ETAT LIKE 'A%' OR
                                                      ETAT LIKE 'P%' OR
                                                      ETAT LIKE 'S%') AND (STAT_ENG = 'E1' OR
                                                      STAT_ENG = 'P1' OR
                                                      STAT_ENG = 'G1')) <= 0) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        ID_CAND
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_EMPL AS PAI_CAND_EMPL_1
                           WHERE        (ID_CAND = PC.ID_CAND) AND (MOTIF_EXCLUS IS NOT NULL) AND (MOTIF_EXCLUS NOT IN ('0')))) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        MOT_ABS
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_PMNT_ABS AS PAI_DOS_PMNT_ABS_1
                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (MOT_ABS = '15' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '16' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '40' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '41' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '45' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '46' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS >= '52' AND MOT_ABS <= '57') OR
                                                     (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (MOT_ABS = '01') AND (CODE_PMNT >= 103522 AND CODE_PMNT <= 103541 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103572 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103573 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103577))) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        STAT_ENG
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_EMPL AS pados
                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (DATE_EFF > GETDATE()))) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        MOTIF_AFF
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.GRH_POSTE_AFFECT AS pados
                           WHERE        (PC.MATR = MATR) AND (MOTIF_AFF LIKE '%S%') AND (DATE_EFF =
                                                         (SELECT        MAX(DATE_EFF) AS Expr1
                                                           FROM            Paie.dbo.GRH_POSTE_AFFECT AS aff
                                                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR))))) AND EXISTS
                         (SELECT        MATR
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_HCHQ_PMNT AS dosem
                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (DATE_FIN > DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE()))) OR
                     (STATUT_CAND IN (2, 3)) AND (DATE_DISPO < GETDATE() OR
                     DATE_DISPO IS NULL) AND
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(ID_CAND) AS Expr1
                             FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_RESULT_ENTREVUE AS pcre
                             WHERE        (ID_CAND = PC.ID_CAND)) > 0) AND
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(MATR) AS Expr1
                             FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_EMPL AS PAI_DOS_EMPL_1
                             WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (ETAT = 'C14' OR
                                                      ETAT = 'C15' OR
                                                      ETAT = 'E1') OR
                                                      (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (ETAT LIKE 'A%' OR
                                                      ETAT LIKE 'P%' OR
                                                      ETAT LIKE 'S%') AND (STAT_ENG = 'E1' OR
                                                      STAT_ENG = 'P1' OR
                                                      STAT_ENG = 'G1')) <= 0) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        ID_CAND
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_EMPL AS PAI_CAND_EMPL_1
                           WHERE        (ID_CAND = PC.ID_CAND) AND (MOTIF_EXCLUS IS NOT NULL) AND (MOTIF_EXCLUS NOT IN ('0')))) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        MOT_ABS
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_PMNT_ABS AS PAI_DOS_PMNT_ABS_1
                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (MOT_ABS = '15' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '16' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '40' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '41' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '45' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '46' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS >= '52' AND MOT_ABS <= '57') OR
                                                     (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (MOT_ABS = '01') AND (CODE_PMNT >= 103522 AND CODE_PMNT <= 103541 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103572 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103573 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103577))) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        STAT_ENG
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_EMPL AS pados
                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (DATE_EFF > GETDATE()))) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        MOTIF_AFF
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.GRH_POSTE_AFFECT AS pados
                           WHERE        (PC.MATR = MATR) AND (MOTIF_AFF LIKE '%S%') AND (DATE_EFF =
                                                         (SELECT        MAX(DATE_EFF) AS Expr1
                                                           FROM            Paie.dbo.GRH_POSTE_AFFECT AS aff
                                                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR))))) AND
                         ((SELECT        DATE_DERN_PAIE
                             FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS
                             WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR)) > DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE())) OR
                     (STATUT_CAND IN (2, 3)) AND (DATE_DISPO < GETDATE() OR
                     DATE_DISPO IS NULL) AND
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(ID_CAND) AS Expr1
                             FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_RESULT_ENTREVUE AS pcre
                             WHERE        (ID_CAND = PC.ID_CAND)) > 0) AND
                         ((SELECT        COUNT(MATR) AS Expr1
                             FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_EMPL AS PAI_DOS_EMPL_1
                             WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (ETAT = 'C14' OR
                                                      ETAT = 'C15' OR
                                                      ETAT = 'E1') OR
                                                      (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (ETAT LIKE 'A%' OR
                                                      ETAT LIKE 'P%' OR
                                                      ETAT LIKE 'S%') AND (STAT_ENG = 'E1' OR
                                                      STAT_ENG = 'P1' OR
                                                      STAT_ENG = 'G1')) <= 0) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        ID_CAND
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_EMPL AS PAI_CAND_EMPL_1
                           WHERE        (ID_CAND = PC.ID_CAND) AND (MOTIF_EXCLUS IS NOT NULL) AND (MOTIF_EXCLUS NOT IN ('0')))) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        MOT_ABS
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_PMNT_ABS AS PAI_DOS_PMNT_ABS_1
                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (MOT_ABS = '15' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '16' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '40' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '41' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '45' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS = '46' OR
                                                     MOT_ABS >= '52' AND MOT_ABS <= '57') OR
                                                     (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (MOT_ABS = '01') AND (CODE_PMNT >= 103522 AND CODE_PMNT <= 103541 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103572 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103573 OR
                                                     CODE_PMNT = 103577))) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        STAT_ENG
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS_EMPL AS pados
                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR) AND (DATE_EFF > GETDATE()))) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        MOTIF_AFF
                           FROM            Paie.dbo.GRH_POSTE_AFFECT AS pados
                           WHERE        (PC.MATR = MATR) AND (MOTIF_AFF LIKE '%S%') AND (DATE_EFF =
                                                         (SELECT        MAX(DATE_EFF) AS Expr1
                                                           FROM            Paie.dbo.GRH_POSTE_AFFECT AS aff
                                                           WHERE        (MATR = PC.MATR))))) AND
                         ((SELECT        DATE_DERN_PAIE
                             FROM            Paie.dbo.PAI_DOS AS PAI_DOS_1
```

Not only is it almost impossible to understand anything (personally I don't) **BUT IT IS 3 TIMES LONGER THEN THE ONE I WROTE**... Unacceptable, is there a way to turn auto format off? If not I'm going to keep my format in a separate file and copy paste it every time.

Comment: Don't use the designer. It does horrible things to formatting. Just right click and "script as create to new window". It will maintain your formatting.

Comment: Don't use *any* of the visual designers in SSMS; they all do horrible things.

Comment: @SeanLange So you suggest i always do this : right click on the view, Script view as, ALTER To, New Query Editor Window ? This will prevent auto formating from happening ?

Comment: Yes it's true ! If i never touch the design button, my view stay exactly as i wanted it thanks, you might want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the designer. It does horrible things to formatting. Just right click and "script as create to new window". It will maintain your formatting. And as Aaron Bertrand commented you should avoid using *any* of the visual designers.

Comment: I agree with you and Aaron, they do horrible things.  But are you saying we should never ever use any of the visual designers?  If so, then why are they there in the first place?

Comment: They work but the code they produce is awful. They exist because a LOT of people can't write their own sql.

Comment: It's just like Access, if you understand the concept of relations, you can do it visualy and it produce a query behind. But if you do it manually, the query you will make will probably be way better than what the visual linking did